# Find the matching postion and date in a List in c#

Tags: c#

I have two Lists - StockData and UpDownData.

```
db1 newStock = new db1();
newStock.Date = (DateTime)reader["Date"];
newStock.High = (double)reader["High"];
StockData.Add(newStock);

db1 newStock2 = new db1();
newStock2.Date = (DateTime)reader2["Date"];
newStock2.Min_Max_Value = (double)reader2["Min_Max_Value"];
UpDownData.Add(newStock2);

int a = 0;
int pos = 0;
DateTime? date1 = null;

while (a < UpDownData.Count && UpDownData.ElementAt(a)?.Date == StockData[i].Date)
{
pos = a;                            
date1 = UpDownData.ElementAt(a).Date;
a++;
}
Console.WriteLine(date1);
```

I am trying to match the date in the **StockData** list with the date in the **UpDownData** list. After I find a match, I use the **position** (**a**) of the element in UpDownData list to print the matched **date**.

But the above code is NOT able to find the matching date. Can someone help?

Thanks

EDIT:

The below image should give you an idea :

[image]

Thus, the matched dates in UpDownData List are 6/30/2015 and 7/16/2015 at position a=0 and a=6 respectively. I only need the POSTION and DATES.

Comment: Yes, read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour debug your code, and look at what happens when you are expecting the match to be made.

Comment: Hint : your while loop only runs when this condition is true : UpDownData.ElementAt(a)?.Date == StockData[i].Date

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're doing here, but if you want help, you should provide a simple, reproducible example. `StockData` and `UpDownData` are lists of `<db1>`? For your example, you could create 2 lists with values, and show structure of `db1`. Is every date value in `StockData` going to be present in `UpDownData`? What should happen if there are duplicates? etc

Comment: @Jonathan: Attaching an image

Comment: @MikNiller: lol ! thanks, to pointing this out. I have resolved this. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication65
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StockData.data = new List<StockData>() {
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/17/2015"), high = 256.9},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/18/2015"), high = 260.7},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/23/2015"), high = 271.2},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/24/2015"), high = 267.9},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2015"), high = 266},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/26/2015"), high = 266.9},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/30/2015"), high = 263.35},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/8/2015"), high = 271},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/10/2015"), high = 271},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/13/2015"), high = 274.35},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/14/2015"), high = 273.6},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/15/2015"), high = 271.7},
                new StockData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/16/2015"), high = 272.75}
            };


            UpDownData.data = new List<UpDownData>() {
                new UpDownData() { date = DateTime.Parse("6/30/2015"), min_max = 263.35},
                new UpDownData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/8/2015"), min_max = 250},
                new UpDownData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/10/2015"), min_max = 236.65},
                new UpDownData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/13/2015"), min_max = 223.3},
                new UpDownData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/14/2015"), min_max = 209.95},
                new UpDownData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/15/2015"), min_max = 196.6},
                new UpDownData() { date = DateTime.Parse("7/16/2015"), min_max = 272.75}
            };

            var results = (from sData in StockData.data
                           join uData in UpDownData.data on sData.date equals uData.date
                           select new { sData = sData, uData = uData })
                          .Where(x => x.sData.high == x.uData.min_max)
                          .Select(x => new { date = x.sData.date, value = x.sData.high }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class StockData
    {
        public static List<StockData> data = new List<StockData>();

        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public double high { get; set; }
    }
    public class UpDownData
    {
        public static List<UpDownData> data = new List<UpDownData>();

        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public double min_max { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate.Appreciate your solution